# how to get request body in varnish

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

I am currently working on a project based on varnish..

we write `vcl` and `vmod`. But the project needs to check the request body. 
How can I get the post request body in `VCL` or `vmod` with a `C function`?

Answer (score 6):

You can do almost everything you want with VCL/VMOD.
You should try to call a VMOD subroutine in `vcl_recv`, and then in C code, write something like below :

- Use `VRT_GetHdr(rec->s, HDR_REQ, "\017Content-Length:");` to read the body length
- Use `HTC_Read(rec->s->htc, body, bodylen);`

And enjoy !

You should take a look at existing vmods https://www.varnish-cache.org/vmods, and be free to look into the varnish API sources.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can.

Varnish generally only deals with Req/Resp headers.
The bodies are passed along without (much) modification.

I you do find a solution please let me know as I'm interested in this as well.