# Get response body from Varnish cache

Tags: caching, vcl, varnish

Is there a way to get the response body (not just the headers) in varnish for logging purposes ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get request body in varnish](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091334/how-to-get-request-body-in-varnish)

Comment: There is a difference. Request body != response body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get resp body by VCL.

But you can get resp body by writing a VMOD and call the VMOD in VCL.

Comment: Is this still the case in 2019?